# Can I load parts external html code without using an iframe on my website?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I'm currently looking for a way to load a div with it's content from an external domain.

Target website (www.aaa.com):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Target website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="hello_world" name="hello_world">
            I want to load this div SO BADLY.
        </div>
        <div id="crappy_div" name="crappy_div">
            I don't want to load this div. :(
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My website (www.bbb.com):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My shiny website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        DIV FROM EXAMPLE ABOVE LOADED HERE DYNAMICALLY
    </body>
</html>
```

So I know I could load the complete `www.aaa.com` content with an `iframe` or use Angluarjs ngInclude or use jQuery but I only want to load one `div` and not the whole content.

How can this be done?

luve u all, have a nice day

Comment: Unless the third party website (aaa.com in your example) supports CORS - which is highly unlikely - then you cannot achieve this in Javascript due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Okay so maybe is there a way to request the content and filter it down to the div I'm targetting?

Comment: I'm afraid not. The response of the request will be blocked. You cannot retrieve any data from a third party in JS unless it is specifically allowed by that third party. This permission is normally only granted on APIs. The usual solution to this problem is to make the request to the third party HTML from your server. You then expose this HTML response from an endpoint on your local domain and have your JS code call that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use first mmethod: https://api.jquery.com/first/

```
var getDiv = $('Extrnal_div').first().html();
```

// get the first div content like this

Replace with your body

`$('body').html($('Extrnal_div').first().html());` //replace your body

Check and let me know

Comment: There are bigger issues than how to access the HTML required.

Answer (score 1):

If CORS is not the issue for you then you can use jquery's `load()` function like this :

```
$('mainPageDiv').load('extPage #divId');
```